# How can I return two values in a controller

Tags: grails

I have a contoller in grails:

```
    [historyInstance: historyInstance]
    [patientInstance: patientInstance]
```

these are my two variables I want to return to the view, but it only allows me to return one

```
    <g:each in="${historyInstance}" var="historyInstances">
    <g:each in="${patientInstance}" var="patientInstances">
```

this is what I have on the view but it only work for one if I'm only returnning one, do you know a way to return the both variables so I can show both elements on the view??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send as many variables as you want, just by a comma, change your controller code to this:

```
 [historyInstance: historyInstance, patientInstance: patientInstance]
```